# how to alter database link name created from dblink?

Tags: postgresql, alter, dblink

I have a connection created via dblink in Postgresql as follows:
`SELECT dblink_connect('conn_db_link', 'server_target');`

Here I used the name `conn_db_link` to represent the connection. Now I would like to change the name to something new. I have tried `ALTER DATABASE LINK conn_db_link RENAME TO new_name`, and it gives me the error.

Is there a way to alter the link name?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no alter for `dblink`. To change the name drop and recreate.